# Unable to generate SSL certificate using letsencrypt

Tags: ssl, wordpress, cname-record, lets-encrypt, aname-record

I am trying to generate an SSL certificate for a subdomain that was purchased using Wordpress. Both the domain and subdomain were purchased from Wordpress. For the subdomain created using Wordpress, I have created a `A` record with IP pointing to some external server. Now I want to generate a SSL certificate for this subdomain. How can I do this?

Here is what I tried using `sudo certbot certonly --webroot` command but gives the following errors.

[image]

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: From where are you calling the command to generate the SSL Certificate? It has to be from the server which you specified in the A Record since LetsEncrypt fires up a temporary Web Server with the command to "challenge" if you actually own it.
At least thats how I understand it.

Comment: @JoCoaker I am calling it from a different server. Can that server be behind a load balancer that has the actual public IP?

Comment: I wrote an answer. Please try it out and get back to me if it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to perform the certificate generation action on the server with the IP you specified in your DNS `A Record`.

**or**

If that is not possible you can also execute the `certbot` command with the `--manuel` flag. ([Official Docs](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#manual))

```
$ sudo certbot certonly --manual

# ...
# ... Asked for domain name and IP logging
# ...
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Please deploy a DNS TXT record under the name
_acme-challenge.<your-domain> with the following value:
 
5TyIfZh7Q38VnQuUvsIWJt0QffSJvCnHNOnlEuRim66
 
Before continuing, verify the record is deployed.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Press Enter to Continue
```

Now here you will need to create a new DNS `TXT` record with the value displayed. (In this case its `2DYIfZh7Q38VnQuUvsIWJt0QffSJvCnHNOnlEuRim66`) And wait a few minutes before pressing enter since the deployment will take some time.
*Don't delete the record afterwards, otherwise renewing will not work!*

Now press enter and it should see sometime like this:

```
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
 
IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/<your-domain>/fullchain.pem
   Your key file has been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/<your-domain>/privkey.pem
   Your cert will expire on xxxx-xx-xx. To obtain a new or tweaked
   version of this certificate in the future, simply run certbot
   again. To non-interactively renew *all* of your certificates, run
   "certbot renew"
 - If you like Certbot, please consider supporting our work by:
 
   Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt:   https://letsencrypt.org/donate
   Donating to EFF:                    https://eff.org/donate-le
```

And now your certificates will be laying in the folder `/etc/letsencrypt/live/<your-domain>/`.

---

[Explanation on how the "HTTP challenge" works](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-acme-acme-03#section-7.2)

Comment: Will this work with the NGINX server already running on port 80? I have 2 VMs behind one public IP. Can I copy the certificate generated in VM?

Comment: @JoCoaker it would be nice to provide some official docs, and not only an answer from you ;)

Comment: @LeRouteur Your very right. I added them. Thanks you.

Comment: @Amanda I am not sure. Never tried that sofar.

Comment: @Amanda as far as I know, yes you can copy the generated certificate on the machine, since your nginx vHost will load the certificate file at execution time.